# Synchronization local database and the remote database using php and c#?

Tags: c#, php, synchronization, database-backups

I want to sync and up-to-date the local database and the remote database concurrently. The owner have four restaurants(`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`) at different places. He maintains same price for products and same quality in all four restaurants. So he uses remote database to change price which used to affect the changed price in all branches. All four branches and remote server have the same database structure and same tables(i.e : A branch has records also other branch. Every branch every tables are uniquely identified by `id` and `branch` field(`id + branch as composite key`).

**Sample table (purchase)**

```
+----+--------+------------+------------+-----+--------------------+---------------------+
| id | branch | item       | unit_price | qty |      added_on      |     last_updated    |
+----+--------+------------+------------+-----+--------------------+---------------------+
| 1  |   A    | Pizza      |   800      |  5  |2018-12-05T15:47:54 | 2018-05-11T15:47:54 |
+----+--------+------------+------------+-----+--------------------+---------------------+
| 2  |   A    | Chicken    |   350      |  5  |2018-12-05T15:49:54 | 2018-05-11T15:50:54 |
+----+--------+------------+------------+-----+--------------------+---------------------+
| 2  |   B    | cappuccino |   280      |  7  |2018-12-05T15:47:24 | 2018-05-11T15:47:24 |
+----+--------+------------+------------+-----+--------------------+---------------------+
```

I have the following code to extract newly added record and updated record (with the field `added_on` and `last_updated`) from local database then upload and import in remote database with a timer. Here the checked time to extract records from local database is stored in a file which will use by the timer.

Now, to-up-to-date the local database(download other branch records) in every branch how can I download the newly inserted records and updated records from the remote server?

**php script on remote server ( To insert on remote database)(execute.php)**

```
<?php

try
  {
    $connect    = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
    $query      = '';
    $table_data = '';
    $filename   = "app_restaurant.json";

    $data  = file_get_contents($filename);
    $array = json_decode($data, true);

    foreach ($array as $set)
      {
        $tblName = $set['tableName'];
        if (sizeof($set['rows']) > 0)
          {
            $query   = '';
            $colList = array();
            $valList = array();
            //  Get list of column names
            foreach ($set['rows'][0] as $colName => $dataval)
              {
                $colList[] = "`" . $colName . "`";
              }
            $query .= "INSERT INTO `" . $tblName . "` \n";
            $query .= "(" . implode(",", $colList) . ")\nVALUES\n";
            //  Go through the rows for this table.
            foreach ($set['rows'] as $idx => $row)
              {
                $colDataA = array();
                //  Get the data values for this row.
                foreach ($row as $colName => $colData)
                  {
                    $colDataA[] = "'" . $colData . "'";
                  }
                $valList[] = "(" . implode(",", $colDataA) . ")";
              }
            //  Add values to the query.
            $query .= implode(",\n", $valList) . "\n";

            //  If id column present, add ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause
            if (in_array("`id`", $colList))                                    
              {
                $query .= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE\n\t";                        
                $tmp = array();
                foreach ($colList as $idx => $colName)
                  {
                    //$tmp[] = $colName." = new.".$colName." ";
                    // Changed the following line to get value from current insert row data
                    $tmp[] = $colName . " = VALUES(" . $colName . ") ";     
                  }
                $query .= implode(",", $tmp) . "\n";
              }
            else
              {
                echo "<p><b>`id`</b> column not found. <i>ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE</i> clause <b>NOT</b> added.</p>\n";
                echo "<p>Columns Found:<pre>" . print_r($colList, true) . "</pre></p>\n";
              }
            echo "<p>Insert query:<pre>$query</pre></p>";
            $r = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

            echo mysqli_errno($connect) . ": " . mysqli_error($connect) . "\n";

            echo "<h1>" . mysqli_affected_rows($connect) . " Rows appended in .$tblName.</h1>";
          }
        else
          {
            echo "<p>No rows to insert for .$tblName.</p>";
          }
      }
  }

catch (Exception $e)
  {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
?>
```

**file up-loader(upload.php)**

```
<?php
    $filepath = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    move_uploaded_file($filepath,"app_restaurant.json");
?>
```

**1.create JSON file from local database**

```
private void btnExportJson_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = @"C:\Users\testeam-PC\Desktop\app_restaurant.json";

            if(File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry! The file is already exists, Please restart the operation","File Exists");
                File.Delete(filePath);
            }
            else
            {
                MySQL mysql = new MySQL();

                var source_result = false;
                source_result = mysql.check_connection(myConString);

                if (source_result == false)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Sorry! Unable to connect with XAMP / WAMP or MySQL.\n Please make sure that MySQL is running.", "Local Database Connection Failure");
                }
                else
                {
                    // MessageBox.Show("Connected");
                    int count = 0;

                    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(myConString))
                    {
                        connection.Open();

                        // get the names of all tables in the chosen database
                        var tableNames = new List<string>();
                        using (var command = new MySqlCommand(@"SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema = @database", connection))
                        {
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@database", "app_restaurant");
                            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                while (reader.Read())
                                    tableNames.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                            }
                        }

                        // open a JSON file for output; use the streaming JsonTextWriter interface to avoid high memory usage
                        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath))

                        // For seperate lines may be huge capacity
                        using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter) { Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, Indentation = 2, IndentChar = ' ' })
                        //using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter) )
                        {
                            // one array to hold all tables
                            jsonWriter.WriteStartArray();

                            foreach (var tableName in tableNames)
                            {
                                //MessageBox.Show(tableName);
                                count += 1;

                                // an object for each table
                                jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
                                jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("tableName");
                                jsonWriter.WriteValue(tableName);
                                jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("rows");

                                // an array for all the rows in the table
                                jsonWriter.WriteStartArray();

                                // select all the data from each table
                                using (var command = new MySqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE (last_updated >= '" + local_checked_time + "') OR (added_on >= '" + local_checked_time + "')", connection))
                                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                                {
                                    while (reader.Read())
                                    {
                                        // write each row as a JSON object
                                        jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
                                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                                        {
                                            jsonWriter.WritePropertyName(reader.GetName(i));
                                            jsonWriter.WriteValue(reader.GetValue(i));
                                        }
                                        jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
                                    }
                                }
                                jsonWriter.WriteEndArray();
                                jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
                            }

                            jsonWriter.WriteEndArray();
                            MessageBox.Show("Totally " + count + " tables circulated", "Success");
                            btnUploadToServer.Enabled = true;
                            // Application.Exit();
                            //btnUploadToServer_Click(sender, e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**2.upload the JSON file to server**

```
   private void btnUploadToServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool connection = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
        if (connection == true)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Internet Available");
            try
            {
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    string filePath = @"C:\Users\testeam-PC\Desktop\app_restaurant.json";
                    var myUri = new Uri(@"http://youraddress.com/path/upload.php");
                    client.UploadFile(myUri, filePath);
                    client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Uploaded", "Success");
            btnExecuteURL.Enabled = true;
            // btnExecuteURL_Click(sender, e);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is no internet connection.\n Please make sure that you have an internet connection.", "No Internet");
        }
    }
```

**3.Execute the file**

```
private void btnExecuteURL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    bool connection = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
    if (connection == true) {
        //MessageBox.Show("Internet Available");
        try {
            // Launch the execution code...
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://youraddress.com/path/execute.php");
        }
        catch(Exception err) {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
    }

    else {
        MessageBox.Show("There is no internet connection.\n Please make sure that you have internet connection.", "No Internet");
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not a php developer and know few about php, but i can say that you approach for updating the remote db is wrong, imagine the code here btnExecuteURL_Click fails or the guy forgets to press that button, you need to automate this process, this is all the microservices do to get sync with each other, to make it simple you can use a MessageBroker (Active MQ, Rabit MQ), and every time sth is updated some daemon/agents which are constantly checking this MsgBrokers will take their msg and update the corresponding db, to update multiple Db in one go you need to implement Fanout Pattern ...

Comment: it gets very complecated if i want to describe the full structure, but when you implement the correct structure then you would have solved several future issues which current structure may cause and make you and other team members bored, if you are using cloud then you have lots of stuff you can use to simplify your job

Comment: Yeah! Thant is under timer event. I separated here for easy understand. But what is MessageBroker?

Comment: please google it, if you need to fix the problem soon, then forget message broker and all i said, because it has a learning curve for you and takes time, so another rapid solution which i can recommend and is fairly faster than my above description is to use replication => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/synchronize-data?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: you can user afterInsertTrigger, use an agent which constantly reads database for unsynced data and toggle an extra column say Sync=1, ... lots of other things, but for me the most pleasant and cleanest way i always enjoy and tend to follow is what i described in my first comment

Comment: Yeah! I read, but I think it is difficult for me. The first comment said MessageBroker. So, how to use here?

Comment: I synced the DB between HeadOfffice and Shop by adding a `isSync` bit column to the table. When new row inserted or updated `isSync` is false/0, the sync service come and picks only the `isSync = 0` and syncs them, after successfull sync  `isSync = 1`. I believe fields **added_on** and **last_updated** will make it complex.

Comment: @affanBajwa, Is that synchronize both way? If I change value on remote DB(HeadOffice), will it change on local(Shop) database?

Comment: @testteam , `isSync` is just here a check, It depends on you if you have written some code that syncs both ways. If you want a row to be synced from DB(HeadOffice) to Shop that while inserting or updating `isSync = 0` **(HO table)** and sync code will pick it up and sync it to local and change `isSync = 1` on both DB's. Hope this comment helped.

Comment: yeah, it is ok. Could you please show how you coded to sync? It will very helpful for me.

Comment: @affanBajwa, why so silent, your contribution will help, please...